# Unable to verify interaction, Spock interpreting '_' (any parameter) as literal '_'

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, spock, junit5

I am trying to test a Spring Boot REST controller using Spock. I am trying to verify that my `exportService.exportAll` method was called once when the controller's `exportMentions` method runs. I get an error saying `too few invocations for exportService.exportAll(_)`. I am  using `_` as I don't care about the parameter.  It does however show that the `exportAll` method was called with another parameter.  It seems like it's interpreting `_` as the literal string `"_"`.  Any idea what I am doing wrong here? My code is below.

Spock error stack trace:

```
Too few invocations for:

1 * exportService.exportAll(_)   (0 invocations)

Unmatched invocations (ordered by similarity):

1 * ExportService.exportAll(2020-08-02T14:19:46.439)
instance == target
|        |  |
|        |  Mock for type 'ExportService' named 'ExportService'
|        false
|        0 differences (100% similarity)
|        Mock for type 'ExportService' named 'ExportService'
|        Mock for type 'ExportService' named 'ExportService'
Mock for type 'ExportService' named 'ExportService'

    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.InteractionScope.verifyInteractions(InteractionScope.java:104)
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.MockController.leaveScope(MockController.java:77)
    at com.vc.cxsocial.controller.ExportControllerSpec.exportMentions: When export is called exportService.exportAll gets called once(ExportControllerSpec.groovy:119)
```

My test:

```groovy
@WebMvcTest(ExportController.class)
class ExportControllerSpec extends Specification {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc

    @Autowired
    private ExportService exportService

    @TestConfiguration
    static class MockConfig {
        def detachedMockFactory = new DetachedMockFactory();

        @Bean
        ExportService exportService() {
            return detachedMockFactory.Mock(ExportService)
        }

        @Bean
        AppConfigProps appConfigProps() {
            return detachedMockFactory.Mock(AppConfigProps)
        }

        @Bean
        CxExportRepository cxExportRepository() {
            return detachedMockFactory.Mock(CxExportRepository)
        }

        @Bean
        MentionRepository mentionRepository() {
            return detachedMockFactory.Mock(MentionRepository)
        }

        @Bean
        JPAQueryFactory jpaQueryFactory() {
            return detachedMockFactory.Mock(JPAQueryFactory)
        }

        @Bean
        @Primary
        LockProvider lockProvider() {
            return detachedMockFactory.Mock(LockProvider)
        }
    }

    @WithMockUser(password = "password")
    def "exportMentions: When export is called exportService.exportAll gets called once" () {
        given:
        def nw = LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(1)
        def dt = nw.toString()

        when: "calling exportMentions"
        // String dt = LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(1).toString()
        mvc.perform(get("/mentions").param("exportDate", dt))

        then:
        1 * exportService.exportAll(_)
    }

}
```

Comment: You’re mixing a Spock test with Spring’s JUnit5/Jupiter annotations. It would surprise me if that worked.

Comment: Please give your questions some more love in the future. No offence meant, but it was next to unreadable. I split the two code blocks mashed up into one for you, added syntax highlighting, fixed many spelling errors and also exchanged the term "function" you used several timed for "method". Java is not a functional language but an OO language.

Comment: @johanneslink, Spock's Spring integration works like this, see [documentation](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.0-M3/all_in_one.html#_spring_boot).

Comment: I cannot see anything obviously wrong in your test, but I am also not a Spring user, I just know Spock quite well. If you have a little [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), ideally a Maven project (Gradle, if not possible otherwise) on GitHub, I would take another look. I need something reproducible. The error message looks very strange, as if there were two mock instances. Which Spock, Groovy, Java and Spring Boot versions are you using, BTW?

Comment: Another question: Can you please show the signature of `exportAll()`? In particular, I like to see the argument list, e.g. if it takes a single argument or varargs.

Comment: @kriegaex I wasn’t aware of that. Thanks!

Comment: @kriegaex  method signature: fun exportAll(exportDate: LocalDateTime)
i'm using Springboot 2.3.2 and org.spockframework:spock-spring:2.0-M3-groovy-2.5

Comment: Any chance you can make the problem reproducible via MCVE? I modified the corresponding test from the Spock framework I liked to previously, so it looks similar to your. No problems there. A reproducer would be helpful.

Comment: @kriegaex I am guessing this issue is related to spock's integration with the spring application context somehow...  Decided to give up and just use JUnit 5 as the spring integration is much more mature... BTW  sorry for the unreadable question, some context: I am legally blind and use a screen reader for everything so the only way for me to format code on here is the ctrl+k shortcut key...

Comment: Sorry you had to give up on what I feel could have been solved, but I understand you wanted to move on from this problem, maybe under a time constraint. Thanks also for explaining your visual condition. You made me aware of the fact how much we seeing people are spoilt by eye candy and how much we assume that everyone is like us. It is a humbling experience to imagine that you do all that programming without the visual guides I take for granted, and I want to express my respect.